# Storing unique values of each column (of a df) in list

Tags: r, for-loop, unique

It is straight forward to obtain unique values of a column using `unique`. However, I am looking to do the same but for multiple columns in a dataframe and store them in a list, all using base R. Importantly, it is not combinations I need but simply unique values for each *individual* column. I currently have the below:

```
# dummy data
df = data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:4]
                ,b = 1:4)

# for loop
cols = names(df)
unique_values_by_col = list()
for (i in cols)
{
  x = unique(i)
  unique_values_by_col[[i]] = x
}
```

The problem comes when displaying `unique_values_by_col` as it shows as empty. I believe the problem is `i` is being passed to the loop as a text not a variable.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can get your snippet to work, replacing `unique(i)` with `unique(df[[i]])`, but a more elegant/efficient way to do this is to use a vectorized function like `lapply` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is almost right, just needs one fix to work:

```
# for loop
cols = names(df)
unique_values_by_col = list()
for (i in cols) {
  x = unique(df[[i]])
  unique_values_by_col[[i]] = x
}
unique_values_by_col
# $a
# [1] A B C D
# Levels: A B C D
# 
# $b
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

`i` is just a character, the name of a column within `df` so `unique(i)` doesn't make sense.

---

Anyhow, the most standard way for this task is `lapply()` as shown by demirev.

Comment: You are right @snoeram I was missing the double square bracket. I understand lapply is the most efficient way (now). However, had to mark yours as answer since the [[ ]] knowledge will be handy in future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not avoid the `for` loop altogether using lapply:

```
lapply(df, unique)
```

Resulting in:

```
> $a
> [1] A B C D
> Levels: A B C D

> $b
> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: A neat solution. Sorry, I had to mark snoram's as the answer as I thought knowledge of for loop will be handy. Nonetheless, have to admit yours is most apt for our case. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Or you have also `apply` that is specifically done to be run on column or line:

```
apply(df,2,unique)
```

result:

```
> apply(df,2,unique)
     a   b
[1,] "A" "1"
[2,] "B" "2"
[3,] "C" "3"
[4,] "D" "4"
```

thought if you want a list `lapply` return you a list so may be better

Comment: This is not advisable because a) the result is not a list and b) column b is of type character now.

Comment: This works too though I do acknowledge one has to be aware of what you mentioned, @markus

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you're trying to do?

```
Map(unique,df)
```

Result:

```
$a
[1] A B C D
Levels: A B C D

$b
[1] 1 2 3 4
```